# Inserting General Tables into drawing Solidworks Macro

Tags: vba, solidworks

I have a user who needs easy access to a drop down list of macros that will easily and quickly import a general table template and will let them place it where they needed it on a cursor click. Currently, the code I have for importing the general table works but I am not familiar enough with the solid works parameters to know which argument to pass to allow the table to be pasted where the user chooses. The specific line in question is `Set swTable = swDrawing.InsertTableAnnotation2(True, 0, 0, swBOMConfigurationAnchor_TopLeft, MATABLE, 2, 1)`

The full code is as follows;

```
Option Explicit

Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks

Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2

Dim swDrawing As SldWorks.DrawingDoc

Dim swTable As SldWorks.TableAnnotation

Const MATABLE As String = "C:\STANDARD Tables\sampleTable.sldtbt"

Sub main()

Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc

If (swModel Is Nothing) Or (swModel.GetType <> swDocDRAWING) Then

swApp.SendMsgToUser ("To be used for drawings only, Open a drawing first and then TRY!")

Exit Sub

End If

Set swDrawing = swModel


Set swTable = swDrawing.InsertTableAnnotation2(True, 0, 0, swBOMConfigurationAnchor_TopLeft, MATABLE, 2, 1)

If Not swTable Is Nothing Then
   swTable.BorderLineWeight = 0
   swTable.GridLineWeight = 0

End If

End Sub
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The second and third parameters (where you have 0 and 0) are used to set the position of the table, but you must also set the first parameter to `False` (which instructs the API to ignore the anchor and use your X and Y coordinates). See [http://help.solidworks.com/2020/english/api/sldworksapi/SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks~SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.IDrawingDoc~InsertTableAnnotation2.html](http://help.solidworks.com/2020/english/api/sldworksapi/SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks%7ESolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.IDrawingDoc%7EInsertTableAnnotation2.html)

So your line would be, for example:

```
Set swTable = swDrawing.InsertTableAnnotation2(False, 10, 10, swBOMConfigurationAnchor_TopLeft, MATABLE, 2, 1).
```

However, a couple of points with your code

Firstly, you'll need to load the document into your VBA Solidworks app object. Your code, as written, won't work because swApp won't have an active document. The best way of doing this would be to offer a file dialog box and load the selected file into the app, using the `OpenDoc6()` function. https://help.solidworks.com/2019/english/api/sldworksapi/Open_Document_Example_VB.htm

Secondly, getting the mouse position and converting that to the X and Y parameters for your `InsetTableAnnotation2()` function will require knowledge of some WinAPIs and a bit of pixel calculation. It's perfectly doable but there's a bit of coding involved. If, on the other hand, you set the `swApp.Visible` to true, then when the table has successfully inserted itself into the Solidworks document, it will be visible to the user and can be dragged around as he/she wishes. You might find this is an easier solution for you.

As an aside, Solidworks is quite strict on licensing and number of users. You would certainly only want one instance of `swApp`, so declare that at module level, but you would probably also need to check for an error in the event that number of licences are exceeded.

Comment: Would you have any idea why the columns and rows arguments that are being passed are being accepted when the [Solidworks API](http://help.solidworks.com/2015/English/api/sldworksapi/SOLIDWORKS.Interop.sldworks~SOLIDWORKS.Interop.sldworks.IModelDocExtension~InsertGeneralTableAnnotation.html) would suggest with a valid template the rows and columns arguments should be ignored?  Secondly, I believe inserting the template at 0,0 may work best because that coordinate will always exist in a drawing and it requires way less coding than using the API's or MathTransform.

Comment: Lastly, @ambie, Could you go more into detail about that last part? I want to put several of these macros together for multiple different tables and have them all be accessible from a drop down so it would be important to me to avoid having the macro occupy a floating license.

Comment: My apologies, that API page is for a different argument that I think may work better for my purposes but let me know your thoughts